# Pro-predicate and Pro-predication

Tags: meaning, terminology, predicate

When I read CGEL, Quirk et al, I found some terminology very obscure.

Now I need help.

What do "pro-predicate" and "pro-predication" exactly mean and how can I distinguish between them?

Comment: Are you asking the difference between "pro-predicate" and "pro-predication"? Also, please tell us what you already understand about them so we don't [reinvent the wheel](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reinvent%20the%20wheel).

Comment: [*“may have done” and “had done” are examples of what ace Anglo-American linguist Lynne Murphy calls “**pro-predicate** ‘do'”*](https://notoneoffbritishisms.com/2017/11/29/pro-predicate-do/) It's a relatively new usage formed from ***predicate*** in the same way as ***pronoun*** comes from ***noun***.

Comment: @gotube,   I don't understand exactly what " pro-predicate" or  " pro-predication "means,  whereby it is hard for me to distinguish between them.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Thanks for your link.  What does " pro-predication" mean? I need help because this terminology can't be found in OED or other dictionaries.

Comment: What does CGEL say about it? What specifically don't you understand? Have you Googled "pro-predicate"? Please [edit] your question to answer these questions. This site requires people asking questions to have made the effort to find the answer themselves first.

Comment: @gotube,  in CGEL, 12.21  page 873, there is only a little information talking about " pro-predicate  DO" and " pro-predication DO" , but not explaining exactly what they mean.  Actually, I've done some research already but the sources I've found  give not much help.  No offence, I doubt few people in this site really understand the exact definition of the above terminology.

Comment: I don't have access to the full text of CEGL, but I'd assume that given ***do*** can apparently be used as a ***pro-verb*** (same as using a ***pronoun*** instead of a noun), and given that derived terms ***verbification*** and ***nounification*** are easily understood even if they're not in a dictionary, we should be able to understand ***pro-verbification*** and ***pro-predication*** in the same way, as derivatives o ***pro-verb*** and ***pro-predicate***.

Comment: You're probably right.  I think I've got a clue to my question.  Moreover,  Your tips help a lot. Thanks.

Comment: @user421993 Lots of people here understand what those terms mean. But we tend not to answer questions here until they meet the minimum standards, including demonstrating that you've made some effort to find the answer yourself. My comment is an effort to get you to improve the question to the point where more people would want to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely a reference to what is also called 'pro-predicative'.

This typically occurs with the pro-form "so", as in

> *They were very happy at that time, or at least they seemed **so**.*

where "so" functions as predicative complement with "very happy" as its antecedent.

Comment: Yes, your answer is one of the solutions related to my question.  As mentioned in CGEL, pro-complement , pro-predication and pro-clause SO , as well as pro-predicate and pro-predication DO are in the list of pro-forms used for substitution.  Thanks.

Comment: @user421993  Oxford Reference define it as 'The use of a pro-form to stand for a predicate or predication'. Pro-predicative "so" is common, as are other pro-forms like "do" in, for example _She drove us to the station but she **did so** reluctantly_, where "did so" is understood as "drove us to the station".

Comment: Agree. Can you offer more information on how to distinguish between these two pieces of terminology?  In my opinion, pro-predicate DO and Pro-predication DO may overlap in   practice, but I am not sure.

Comment: @user421993 I think you have your answer: any pro-form that functions as part or all of the predicate of a clause.